# Laravel eloquent multi relations search column

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, where-clause, eloquent

Trying to figure out how to make a search on a specific table from the below Laravel Eloquent query:

```
$user = \App\User::with('profile', 'languages', 'contacts', 'photos', 'jobs', 'offices', 'socials')->get();
```

What I'm trying to filter is a user where in the **profile table** the `'full_name_slug', '=', 'john-doe'`

I've tried forming the **where clause** like `'profile.full_name_slug', '=', 'john-doe'` but without success.

Probably this is quite simple but couldn't figure it out from all the Laravel 5 documentation.

Thanks in advance for any help
Cheers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The right syntax to do

```
User::whereHas('profile', function ($query) {

   $query->where('full_name_slug', '=', 'john-doe');
})->get();
```

Comment: Thanks! I've put it to work with your help with:
`User::whereHas('profile', function ($query) {

   $query->where('full_name_slug', '=', 'john-doe');
})->with('languages', 'contacts', 'photos', 'jobs', 'offices', 'socials')->get();`

This way it returns the full object I need.